# simple Cache Simulator

Tags: c, caching, simulator

part of an assignment I am trying to implement a very simple cache simulator, but my program is returning wrong result. I can't figure out whether the problem is with the logic of how I counted hits/misses or some coding error. I suspect its the way I count the hits and misses. I will write the logic of how I counted hits/miss/evictions, if anybody spotted an error please point out.

instruction is load ( L) -> if found hit++, if not found miss++ ( but now we have to store it, so if line empty, store in empty line, if no empty lines, find Least Recently Used line data and evict it, increment eviction++)

instruction is Modification(M) -> if found hit+=2, (cause one for loading another for storing), if not found miss++,(now since its a miss find empty line to store, empty line found hit++, empty line not found eviction++, search for Least Recently Used line, found, store contents in that line hit++)

instruction is Store (S) -> if empty line found hit++, if no empty line eviction++, evict one with LRU flag ,store data there, hit++

Comment: What if you get a store on a memory address that already exists in cache? I don't see why you have both S and M instructions - you only need one.

Comment: Well I wrote it to understand the logic of it,its implemented differently in the code

Comment: You didn't answer my question

Comment: @RedAlert oh sorry, Well I only realized it when you pointed out.So I guess that's one deficiency that i have to get rid of! do u think the other parts are ok?

Comment: After you fix (S), you can get rid of (M), since (M) should be implemented as (L) followed by (S), and not as an overly complicated special case.  Or to put it another way, if all of your logic is correct, then (L) followed by (S) at the same address, should have exactly the same effect as (M).

Comment: @user3386109 I will do that for sure. But still I don't get the result. there are different testing files, i get the correct result only with one of them. do you think the logic is correct? (for L, M, S)

Comment: The logic for (L) and (M) appear correct. You don't describe how you implement ["Least Recently Used"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#LRU), so I can only comment that `LRU` is different from hit count.  Also, most cache's are implemented in lines, which means that multiple addresses map to the same cache location. Not sure if you're doing that or not.

Comment: @user3386109 for LRU, every line has an lru integer, whenever there is data in line, and it;s not used then i increment the lru. when i want to evict one, i try to find the lru with the largest number and put data on that line.

Comment: Yup, that sounds right. Be careful that the LRU count doesn't overflow and wrap back to 0.

Comment: You are not describing LRU, you are describing LFU. For example, take two lines `a` and `b`. Given the sequence `L(b), L(b), L(a)`, your algorithm will evict `a` before `b`, even though it has been used more recently.

Comment: @RedAlert I thought what I was using was LRU. wiki page( General implementations of this technique require keeping "age bits" for cache-lines and track the "Least Recently Used" cache-line based on age-bits. In such an implementation, every time a cache-line is used, the age of all other cache-lines changes.)

Comment: It is possible to implement LRU using age bits (and is the most efficient way to do so in hardware), but not using the method you've described. You need to use bit shifts, not increment a counter. There are simpler ways to implement LRU in software (such as using a linked list). I advise you go that route, since your understanding level is low.